# LinearLayout's click listener is never called

Tags: android, mobile, android-linearlayout, android-3.0-honeycomb

Trying to get an onclick listener working on a linearlayout but its never called :(. Have enabled clickable and focsuable (both modes) and still cant get the click listener to respond. Platform details: Android 3.0.. Any help?? Code below

```
           <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/menu_items_button"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/gen_margin_xsmall"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/gen_margin_xsmall"
                android:background="@drawable/rule_bg_menu_button"
                android:clickable="true"
              android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/menu_items"
                    android:tag="image"
                />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:tag="text"
                    android:text="@string/menu_items_icon_txt"
                    style="@style/textDisplay.mediumLarge"
                />

            </LinearLayout>
```

and in the code to add the event listener

```
_itemsButton = (LinearLayout) menu.findViewById(R.id.menu_items_button);
final Intent itemsIntent = new Intent(this, ItemsActivity.class);
_itemsButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {    
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(itemsIntent); //Never called!
                }
            }
        );
```

The reason I'm doing this and not using an Image button instead is because the background of the "button" is state based (gradient changes) but also the image and in order to combine to the two on click / on focus, I used a linearlayout which has an ImageView in itself.. any suggestions on why the clickListener is not working on the linearLayout?

thx

Comment: do you see the state change when you click the layout?

Comment: yes the state did change, the background color changed which is defined in the state drawable

Comment: @pzulw got it right, the imageview (inside the linearlayout) is getting the click.. maybe i should make it "un-clickable" or propagate the click to its parent somehow..

Comment: this is weird, an `ImageView` is not supposed to handle clicks by default. What if you click on the `TextView`? By default the click should pass through (just tried with the `ImageView` and here, API 8, it works like that) EDIT: maybe setting a statelistdrawable as image makes it clickable? going to try

Comment: The problem with this approach is that if, for example, the LinearLayout had background that changed based on pressed state, etc., those effects will be lost. Making the subviews not respond to click events sometimes helps, but not always (imageView.setClickable(false), etc.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did the click go to the ImageView instead of the LinearLayout?   Try clicking in the pad area (if any) or try putting the click listenner on the ImageView1.

Comment: SICK!! u rock.. yes it did, how can I bubble it up top to its parent (the linearlayout?)

Comment: The easy way is to set the same click listener on the image view and the text view.

View.OnClickListener activityLauncher = new View.OnClickListener() {... }
layout.setOnClickListener(activityLauncher);
imageView.setOnClickListener(activityLauncher);
textView.imageView.setOnClickListener(activityLauncher);

Comment: I know this is late, but you can also set the ImageView as not clickable in the XML: `android:clickable="false"`

Answer (score 3):

(adding my response as a new answer so that I can use the PRE tag.)

The easy way is to set the same click listener on the image view and the text view.

```
View.OnClickListener activityLauncher = new View.OnClickListener() {... }
layout.setOnClickListener(activityLauncher);
imageView.setOnClickListener(activityLauncher);
textView.imageView.setOnClickListener(activityLauncher);
```

Answer (score -3):

The width of your `LinearLayout` is set to **"0dip"**, you should see nothing on the screen.

If the width is changed to **"FULL_PARENT"**, that works. Please check your code carefully again.

Comment: I see the button fine. The width is 0 dip because there is a weight associated with it which handles the width.

Comment: Then try make the LinearLayout fill the whole screen, you will find that the layout indeed receives the click event. I've tried your code, it works:)

Comment: Two notes: 0dp (or 0dip) is the appropriate layout_width when used with layout_weight.  Second, it would be "fill_parent", not "full_parent", and in newer Android versions you can use "match_parent" instead